# Issues with structure arrays and obtaining array string from user integer input

Tags: vb.net

I'm stuck on this hw question which wants me to use a structure and make arrays that includes 2 datatypes: the minimum points needed for a grade and the string for the actual grade letter. So when the user inputs a certain amount of points, the application should find the inputted integer and display the correct grade. With the code I have so far, I think I would need to subtract the inputted integer but I am having trouble getting it to work correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
Public Class frmMain
Structure GradeCalculation
    Public intPoint As Integer
    Public strGrade As String
End Structure
Private arrGradeList(4) As GradeCalculation

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub txtPoints_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPoints.Enter
    txtPoints.SelectAll()
End Sub

Private Sub txtPoints_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPoints.KeyPress
    ' allows only numbers and the Backspace key

    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtPoints_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPoints.TextChanged
    lblGrade.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    Dim intPointInput As Integer
    Dim intSub As Integer

    Integer.TryParse(txtPoints.Text, intPointInput)

    Do Until intSub = arrGradeList.Length OrElse
        intPointInput = arrGradeList(intSub).intPoint
        intSub += 1
    Loop

    If intPointInput < arrGradeList.Length Then
        lblGrade.Text = arrGradeList(intSub).strGrade
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    arrGradeList(0).intPoint = 0
    arrGradeList(0).strGrade = "F"
    arrGradeList(1).intPoint = 300
    arrGradeList(1).strGrade = "D"
    arrGradeList(2).intPoint = 350
    arrGradeList(2).strGrade = "C"
    arrGradeList(3).intPoint = 420
    arrGradeList(3).strGrade = "B"
    arrGradeList(4).intPoint = 470
    arrGradeList(4).strGrade = "A"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    Dim intPointInput As Integer = CInt(txtPoints.Text)

    For Each grade As GradeCalculation In arrGradeList
        If intPointInput >= grade.intPoint Then
            lblGrade.Text = grade.strGrade
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I should probably clarify that the array has to only include the minimum integer but for the user input any integer should work.

Comment: Ive edited the code, the code now loops through each GradeCalculation and checks if the given points are equal to or greater then the desired points

Comment: Oh my. Thank you so much! I was too focused on sticking with the Do Until.